# Docker-Compose does not work on Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, server, docker-compose

I installed a new Windows Server 2022 and then followed the instructions to install Docker and Docker Compose on the Server.  I also installed WSL and a Ubuntu20-04.
Then, I tried to run a docker-compose up command and it failed with the following error message.

[image]

Is there anyway for me to use Windows Server 2022 to run docker-compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few steps here:

1. Set up your environment on that build, following the instructions here:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tab...
2. Given it's an Insider build, you may need this step as well:
   https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-insider
3. Then you can run a command like this to get your Windows Server 2022 Preview container images:
   docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/insider:10.0.20298.1

As a reference, these are Docker Hub Windows Server Base OS container image Insider release pages:
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-insider
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver-insider